# Test class error - Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.OpportunityId

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am trying to write a test class for a tigger and ansure why I am getting the following error -

> Field is not writeable: OpportunityPartner.OpportunityId at line 40
> column 68
>
> // test 2: 1 opppart, not End-User == null
>
> OpportunityPartner opppart1 = new OpportunityPartner(OPPORTUNITYID=o.id, ACCOUNTTOID=a1.id, role='Consultant');
>
> insert opppart1;

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Full Class

```
@isTest
private class Populate_Partner_onOpp_fromopppart {

    static testMethod void EndUserPartnerTest() {
        // create test account

        Account a1 = new Account(Name = 'My Account A', Industry = 'School Bus', Phone = '9996661234', Territory__c = 'School Bus - Canada', Status__c = 'customer', Price_Level__c = 'standard', 
BillingStreet = 'to come', BillingCity = 'to come', BillingCountry = 'canada', BillingPostalCode = '90210', BillingState = 'Alberta', 
ShippingStreet = 'to come', ShippingCity = 'to come', ShippingCountry = 'canada', ShippingPostalCode = '90210', ShippingState = 'Alberta' );
        insert a1;   

        Account a2 = new Account(Name = 'My Account B', Industry = 'School Bus', Phone = '9996661234', Territory__c = 'School Bus - Canada', Status__c = 'customer', Price_Level__c = 'standard', 
BillingStreet = 'to come', BillingCity = 'to come', BillingCountry = 'canada', BillingPostalCode = '90210', BillingState = 'Alberta', 
ShippingStreet = 'to come', ShippingCity = 'to come', ShippingCountry = 'canada', ShippingPostalCode = '90210', ShippingState = 'Alberta' );
        insert a2;  

        Account a3 = new Account(Name = 'My Account C', Industry = 'School Bus', Phone = '9996661234', Territory__c = 'School Bus - Canada', Status__c = 'customer', Price_Level__c = 'standard', 
BillingStreet = 'to come', BillingCity = 'to come', BillingCountry = 'canada', BillingPostalCode = '90210', BillingState = 'Alberta', 
ShippingStreet = 'to come', ShippingCity = 'to come', ShippingCountry = 'canada', ShippingPostalCode = '90210', ShippingState = 'Alberta' );
        insert a3;  

        Account a4 = new Account(Name = 'My Account D', Industry = 'School Bus', Phone = '9996661234', Territory__c = 'School Bus - Canada', Status__c = 'customer', Price_Level__c = 'standard', 
BillingStreet = 'to come', BillingCity = 'to come', BillingCountry = 'canada', BillingPostalCode = '90210', BillingState = 'Alberta', 
ShippingStreet = 'to come', ShippingCity = 'to come', ShippingCountry = 'canada', ShippingPostalCode = '90210', ShippingState = 'Alberta' );
        insert a4;  



        // create test opp
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(name='test Opp', closedate=system.today(), stagename='Initial Communication', Market__c = 'Transit', ACCOUNTID=a4.id);
        insert o;

        // test 1: no oppparts == null
        o = [select EndUser_Partner__c from opportunity where id=:o.id];
        o.description='initial test';
        update o;
        system.assert(o.EndUser_Partner__c == null);

        // test 2: 1 opppart, not End-User == null
        OpportunityPartner opppart1 = new OpportunityPartner(OPPORTUNITYID=o.id, ACCOUNTTOID=a1.id, role='Consultant');
        insert opppart1;
        opppart1 = [select createddate, opportunityid, ACCOUNTTOID, role, isprimary from OpportunityPartner where id = :opppart1.id];
        system.debug('************ opppart is:'+opppart1);
        o.description='test';
        update o;
        o = [select EndUser_Partner__c from opportunity where id=:o.id];
        system.assert(o.EndUser_Partner__c == null);

        // test 3: 1 opppart, End-User == c1
        opppart1.role == 'End-User';
        update opppart1;
        o.description='test2';
        update o;
        o = [select EndUser_Partner__c from opportunity where id=:o.id];
        system.assert(o.EndUser_Partner__c == a1.id);

        // test 4: 2 opppart, 1 not End-User, 1 End-User == c2
        OpportunityPartner opppart2 = new OpportunityPartner(opportunityid=o.id, ACCOUNTTOID=a2.id, role='End-User', isprimary=true);
        insert opppart2;

        opppart2 = [select createddate, opportunityid, role, ACCOUNTTOID, isprimary from OpportunityPartner where id = :opppart2.id];
        opppart1.role == 'Consultant';
        update opppart1;

        o.description='test3';
        update o;
        o = [select EndUser_Partner__c from opportunity where id=:o.id];
        system.assert(o.EndUser_Partner__c == a2.id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to read, please put some effort into formatting it. You should also put some effort into utility methods that help you repeat yourself less.

Answer (score 3):

[OpportunityPartner](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitypartner.htm) records are read-only and are created automatically by Salesforce

> when a Partner object is created for a partner relationship between an account and an opportunity.

> ### Creating an Account-Opportunity Partner Relationship
>
> When you create a partner relationship between an account and an opportunity (when you create a Partner object and specify the OpportunityId field), the API automatically creates an OpportunityPartner with the corresponding values:
>
> - The value of the Partner field `AccountToId` maps to the value of the OpportunityPartner field `AccountToId`.
> - The values of the `OpportunityId`, `Role`, and `IsPrimary` fields in both objects are the same.
> - If you set the `IsPrimary` value to 1 (true) upon insert of a new OpportunityPartner, any other existing primary partners for that opportunity will automatically have the `IsPrimary` value set to 0 (false).

Also, they share the [00I keyprefix](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#00I) with [Partner](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partner.htm). As such, I tend to think of them as a specialised view over Partner.

So you shouldn't need to explicitly insert the record during a test case. The Partner object that you insert will have `accountToId` to an Account and `opportunityId` to an Opportunity on a different Account.